# Display button in the same position of the image on click

Tags: html, css

Wanted to know if a button can be displayed in the same position as the image.

[image]

[image]

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
  </div>
```

[image]

How can Image and text be displayed ina table format

Comment: What do you mean by "same position"?

Comment: N.B. don't use float, there are some "new" properties like flexbox or grid.

Comment: I did not understand the meaning of your question

Comment: The code you are using will not be able to fit 3 items in a row because of the extra padding width. While you can get round this using box-sizing I'd suggest you instead drop trying to size things yourself and drop the float, instead look into CSS grid with grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr. Then you can have your buttons in a div in amongst the other items.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. 

So when you click the first image. I want the image to disappear & then display the buttons as shown in the second image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't really understand what you wanted, but I did it from the picture.

The code is wrong in my opinion you can read about gridd css so that in the future you can do it correctly [css grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).

Or the cssportal website can help [css-flexbox-generator/](https://www.cssportal.com/css-flexbox-generator/)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 19rem;
}
button {  
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 4rem auto 0rem auto;
  background-color: #447bad;
  border-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 10px 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <button style="background: #4CAF4F;">Green</button>
    <button>Blue</button>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

The second method, click the image disappears, the buttons appear.

```js
let child1 = document.querySelector("#child1");
child1.onclick = function () {
    document.querySelector("#child1 > img").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#child1 > .btn-click").style.display = "block";
};
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
.btn-click{
  display:none;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 19rem;
}
button {  
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 4rem auto 0rem auto;
  background-color: #447bad;
  border-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 10px 21px;
}
.grid-item{
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item" id="child1">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="btn-click">
      <button style="background: #4CAF4F;">Green</button>
      <button>Blue </button>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="">
  </div>  
</div>
```

The code is not responsive.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. So when you click the first image. I want the image to disappear & then display the buttons as shown in the second image.

Comment: @melwyn-mendonca I added the method you wrote me. when the images are pressed, buttons appear and the image disappears. Show the hidden code snippet below

Comment: @Segiu. Thank you for your Help. I wanted to know how to display images and text side by side and in a table format. Added the image in the question

Answer (score 2):

if you mean you want the button be inside the picture here what it is

```
img {
position : relitive ;
}
button {
position : absolute ;
top : 0;
left : 0;
}
```

I dont know where is your button tag if it is inside your div class:"colume" get  it out of there

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it with flexbox usage rather than `float`. Check out the Codepen I setup with an example in it ->

https://codepen.io/martin_f/pen/vYdYPNp

**-EDIT to include relevant code here-**

With flexbox usage you can go about making use of `flex-direction` / `justify-content` / `align-items` CSS rules to get the effect you want here ->

```css
.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.column,
.column-btn {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
}

.column img {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.column-btn {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column-btn button {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  width: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

.column-btn button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.column-btn button.blue-btn {
  background-color: #008cba;
}

.column-btn button.green-btn {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483921020237-2ff51e8e4b22?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506905925346-21bda4d32df4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column-btn">
    <button class="green-btn">Green</button>
    <button class="blue-btn">Blue</button>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448375240586-882707db888b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506905925346-21bda4d32df4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

And you end up with something like ->
[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Comment: fair play, will edit it now